# Dual/triple booting Surface Pro?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, microsoft-surface

Before I purchase a Surface Pro, I would like to know how well it dual boots. I often develop for Mac, Windows, and Linux, so I highly value in a computer the community-supported ability to natively run multiple operating systems. Does grub work well for Windows 8 / Ubuntu on the Surface Pro?

Has anyone been able to dual boot Mac OS X / Windows 8 on the Surface Pro?

Comment: You can't (legally) install OSX on anything but a Mac.  Other than that, Dual-booting is no different from other systems. Just watch out for EFI.

Comment: Unlike the Surface RT on which Secure Boot cannot be turned off, this is not an obstacle on the Pro. (With recent versions of Linux even this shouldn't be a problem.) As long as all the hardware works (i.e. driver availability), I don't foresee any problems dual booting at all. Indeed, lots of articles on the net and even YouTube videos to show many people have already accomplished this. The Pro's just like any other Windows portable machine you've used in the past. Edit: Since Hyper-V's available OOTB, you can run a Linux VM from a VHD as well, or of course via your VM of choice.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine OSX working on a surface pro due to the custom/proprietary hardware being used... but linux and windows should co-exist happily so long as you have enough disk space.

When dual booting, install windows first! Then install linux, which will allow Grub to take over and manage booting. Essentially this will boot to Grub, then will chain-boot your windows bootloader if you select windows from the menu.

Good luck!